# Reverse-engineer PostgreSQL query into diagram

Tags: database, diagram, postgresql, er-diagram

Is there a tool that can show a diagram of tables involved for a PostgreSQL query?

**Must support:**

- WITH syntax
- Subqueries
- Joins
- Lateral joins

**Nice to have:**

- Columns involved
- Recursive expand definitions of involved views/mat views.

**So far I've tried:**

- DBeaver Pro
- DbVisualizer Pro
- Datagrip
- PostgreSQL Maestro

But they all choke into one or more of the "must" requirements, and cannot parse the query. Note that the queries I am trying are valid and return results in all of the above tools, but they can't be parsed back into a diagram.